# Is it possible to directly pump a laser using sunlight?

Tags: laser

Typically in the old days one would use a flash tube to pump a ruby crystal. Is there any way, or any lasing material, that could use concentrated sunlight directly for either continuous or pulsed operation?
I am familiar with [some attempts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar-pumped_laser) but the materials available seem rather limited

Comment: Sunlight has such a broad spectrum that I suspect many things could theoretically be pumped by it.  The efficiency will be very low however.  BTW, are you familiar with the [Martian atmosphere CO$_2$ laser](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1985SvAL...11..162S)?

Comment: It probably [already exists](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/408698/solar-powered-laser/)

Comment: It indeed exists, and is developed further. DOI: 10.1364/OE.21.025107

Answer (score 1):

They already exist. "Solar-pumped lasers already exist: they work by concentrating sunlight onto crystalline materials such as neodymium-doped yttrium aluminium garnet, causing them to emit laser light." ([source](http://www.technologyreview.com/news/408698/solar-powered-laser/))
They have been innovated though, so there are more efficient method to make solar-powered lasers now.

Comment: I know, IIRC it was referenced in the wikipedia article. However, there must be more lasing mediums than those mentioned. Ideally I would like one that operated at visual wavelengths.